# Spark read lz4 files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to read LZ4 in Spark.

```
val file = sc.textFile("test.log.lz4")
val data = sc.newAPIHadoopFile[LongWritable,Text,TextInputFormat]("test.log.lz4")
  .map(_._2.toString)
```

Both file.count() and data.count() returns 0.

checknative:

```
Native library checking:
hadoop:  true /usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
zlib:    true /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
snappy:  true /usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/lib/native/libsnappy.so.1
lz4:     true revision:99
bzip2:   false 
openssl: true /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
```